# CSV to Google Sheet with different limiters

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to convert some CSV files but the format of the files is making it difficult for me.

I have CSV files that use two different limiters, in the TYPE1 ";" is used. and in TYPE2 "|" is used. And the data inside is not formatted the same, so I'm interested in keeping it separate.

The code I have works fine for one of the two format types (in this case for TYPE1). Right now what it does is grab all the files from a folder and import them into a tab removing duplicate headers. I would be interested if it took all the TYPE1 files and unified them in one tab, and all the TYPE2 files in another tab.

File names begin with "TYPE1_xxxx" and "TYPE2_xxxx"

Thanks!

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu(" RUN ")
    .addItem("Importar CSV's", "main")
    .addToUi();
}

function main(){
  var skip_header = true    
  importCsvFiles(skip_header)
}

function importCsvFiles(skipHeader) {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CSVfolder").next()
  const files = folder.getFiles()
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  let headerWritten = false

  while (files.hasNext()){
    const file = files.next()
    const data = file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
    const csv = Utilities.parseCsv(data, ';')
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    
    // skip headers
    if (skipHeader && headerWritten) {
      csv.splice(0,1)           
      
    } else if (skipHeader && headerWritten == false) {
      headerWritten = true
    }
    
    sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function importCsvFiles(skipHeader) {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CSVfolder").next()
  const files = folder.getFiles()

  let headerWritten = false

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next()
    console.log(file.getName())
    let data = file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
    let delimitor = ''
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

    if (file.getName().includes('TYPE1')) {
      let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TYPE1')
      let delimitor = ';'
    }
    else {
      let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TYPE2')
      let delimitor = '|'
    }

    const csv = Utilities.parseCsv(data, delimitor)
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()

    // skip headers
    if (skipHeader && headerWritten) {
      csv.splice(0, 1)

    } else if (skipHeader && headerWritten == false) {
      headerWritten = true
    }

    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv)

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works fast, but the "delimitor" is not working well, all the CSV's are imported in the same tab with an incorrect delimitation.

Comment: which delimitation ? can you share a sample of type1 file and type2 file ?

Comment: what do you see in console ? there could be the names of the imported files